# Uso de ajax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy exportando a `Excel`

Pero necesito usar `ajax` ,
porque necesito que cuando le de en  `Exportar a Excel` me deje en la misma vista

Esto es desde mi controlador donde tengo : Mi `ActionResult` de index y `void` donde exporto a `excel`

```
    using RecursosHumanos.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace RecursosHumanos.Controllers
    {    
        [Authorize]
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private RecursosHumanosEntities db = new RecursosHumanosEntities();

     public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public void ExportarExcel2(string[] Deducciones,List<DeduccionesEmpleadoViewModel> DeduccionesZ)
            {


            }

    }
   }
```

Esto en es mi vista, es donde necesito el `ajax`

```
 @{ 
        ViewBag.DashBoard = "active";
        ViewBag.Title = "DashBoard";

    }
    @{ 
        int i = 0;
    }

    @section _Header
    {
        <!-- Page header -->
        <div class="page-header page-header-default">
            <div class="page-header-content">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h4><i class="icon-arrow-left52 position-left"></i> <span class="text-semibold">Home</span> - Dashboard</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="heading-elements">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="breadcrumb-line">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="/Home/Index"><i class="icon-home2 position-left"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Dashboard</li>

                </ul>



                @*<ul class="breadcrumb-elements"></ul>*@
                <ul class="breadcrumb-elements">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="icon-gear position-left"></i>
                            Opciones
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

                            @*<li><a href="@Url.Action("ExportarExcel","Planilla", new { FechaInicio=ViewBag.FechaInicio, FechaFin= ViewBag.FechaFin , TipoPlanillaid = ViewBag.TipoPlanillaId, NumeroPlanillas = ViewBag.PlaNumero, Deducciones = ViewBag.Deduccionesp})"><i class="icon-file-excel position-left"></i> Exportar a Excel</a></li>*@
                            <li><a id="BotonEnviar" href="javascript:document.getElementById('frm-planilla').submit()"><i class="icon-file-excel position-left"></i> Exportar a Excel</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
   <form action="@Url.Action("ExportarExcel2")" method="post" id="frm-planilla">
   @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     <input type="text" name="[@i].DedId" value="@i" />
   }
</form>
```

al momento de darle en la opción exportar a `excel` me deje en la misma vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Con ajax no es posible exportar el archivo, deberás hacerlo a través de un iframe al cual le debes pasar los parametros por GET. De la siguiente forma lo hago yo para exportar archivos a excel independiente del lenguaje que estés utilizando por el lado del server.

```
/*Si no existe el iframe lo agrego al dom*/
if($('#iframe-download').length==0)
        $('body').append('<iframe id="iframe-download" style="border:0px;display:none"/>');

/*modifico los parametros de la URL de mi script que genera el archivo de descargas*/    
$('#iframe-download').attr('src',url+'?param1=valor1&....');
```

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quiere @Antonio Diaz   es desde ajax  llamar el metodo del controlador que se encarga de exportar

Comment: independiente del como haga la llamada lo que necesita según su post es "... necesito que cuando le de en  Exportar a Excel me deje en la misma vista...", con ajax no puede porque Javascript no permite guardar archivos en el sistema de archivos del usuario, sabiendo esto es que es necesaria una solución de este tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para generar reporte en c# yo utilizo el completo de ClosedXML

Aca te dejo un pequeño tutorial
https://www.variablenotfound.com/2013/03/generar-archivos-excel-como-un-senor.html

Te comparto como hago que el reporte corra con Ajax.

```
public ActionResult Reporte()
    {


        string nombre = "Nombre de tu archivo";

        //aquí closed xml genera el archivo Excel
        var workbook = ReporteUno.GenerarReporte();

        //Genera una llave única para el archivo quevas abrir
        string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Salvas el archive en alguna parte de la memoria de forma temporal
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            TempData[handle] = stream.ToArray();
        }

        //Aca guardas el nombre y la llave del archivo que vas a ganerar
        GuiasArgs nueco = new GuiasArgs();
        nueco.FileGuid = handle;
        nueco.FileName = nombre;
        return Json(nueco, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Ahora debes usar el siguiente cogido javascript.
En este caso uso Jquery

```js
$.ajax({
                       datatype: 'JSON',
                       cache: false,
                       url: '/Controlador/Reporte,
                       beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
 
 //Esto es una acción que realiza la vista mientras se cargan le excel, en este caso yo use .BlockUI que es una librería javasrcript, pero puedes usar un div y una imagen como se ve en las líneas comentadas
                           //$('#loading').html('<img style="width: 140px;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;" src="./Img/ajax-loading.gif" alt="spinner" />');
                           //$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="/Content/images/throbber.gif" /> Por favor espere...</h1>' });
 
                       },
                       data: {
                           Aca pasas tus parametros
 
 
                       },
                       success: function (data) {
                           
Aca desapareces la imagen que cargaste al principio

   //$('#loading').empty();
                           //$.unblockUI();
 
//Aca vamos a llamar la url que nos mostrara el archivo sin salirse de la página actual
                           window.location = '/Controlador/DownloadFile?fileGuid=' + data.FileGuid
                                             + '&filename=' + data.FileName;
                       },
 
 
                       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 
 
 
 
                       }
 
                   })
```

Finalmente en tu controlador pones el siguiente código

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)
    {
        if (TempData[fileGuid] != null)
        {
            byte[] data = TempData[fileGuid] as byte[];
            return File(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName + ".xlsx");
        }
        else
        {

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

Es cuestión de que lo adaptes a tus componentes, se ve algo loco pero en realidad es muy sencillo.

Saludos